# LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__dso_handle' which could not be resolved!

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

Компилирую простейшую программу Hello World

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world\n";
  return 0;
}
```

С помощью комманды

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -S bla.cpp
```

Затем запускаю результирующий байткод:

```
lli bla.ll
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '__dso_handle' which could not be resolved!
```

Использую Fedora Linux 23 64-bit

Comment: ключик `-lstdc++` ?